# Scikit-Learn: How to retrieve prediction probabilities for a KFold CV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I have a dataset that consists of images and associated descriptions. I've split these into two separate datasets with their own classifiers (visual and textual) and now I want to combine the predictions of these two classifiers to form a final prediction.

However, my classes are binary, either 1 or 0. I end up with two lists of n_samples filled with 1's and 0's. I assume that for most algorithms/classifiers this is not enough information to make a useful prediction (i.e. when one classifier predicts 1 and the other 0).

Therefore I thought I could use the probabilities of the predictions as some form of decisive weighting. SVC in SKlearn has the `svm.SVC.predict_proba` function. Returning an array that may look like this:

```
[[ 0.9486674   0.0513326 ]
 [ 0.97346471  0.02653529]
 [ 0.9486674   0.0513326 ]]
```

But I can't seem to combine this with my Kfold cross-validation function `cross_validation.cross_val_predict` as this is a prediction function on its own and does not include a similar probability prediction output. Is there any way to combine the two? Or am I missing something?

Possibly: Am I attacking my problem entirely wrong and is there a better way to combine the predictions of two binary classifiers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a GridSearchCrossValidation instead of just CV. CV is used for performance evaluation and itself doesn't fit the estimator actually.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

# unbalanced classification
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, weights=[0.1, 0.9])

# use grid search for tuning hyperparameters
svc = SVC(class_weight='auto', probability=True)
params_space = {'kernel': ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf']}
# set cv to your K-fold cross-validation
gs = GridSearchCV(svc, params_space, n_jobs=-1, cv=5)
# fit the estimator
gs.fit(X, y)
gs.predict_proba(X)

Out[136]: 
array([[ 0.0074817 ,  0.9925183 ],
       [ 0.03655982,  0.96344018],
       [ 0.0074933 ,  0.9925067 ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.02487791,  0.97512209],
       [ 0.01426704,  0.98573296],
       [ 0.98574072,  0.01425928]])
```

Comment: Thanks! This works excellent! One question: if I understand correctly GridSearchCV is used to find the best parameters. You pass 3 different kernels, this means he will test for all three right (resulting in longer computation)? If I just pass one does it behave the same as a cross validation, with the (only) difference that it allows me to fit the estimator and output in probabilities? Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The GridSearchCV performs CV on each combination of parameters. So, supplying just your favourite parameter combination would let the estimator just do the CV part.

Comment: Is this the results from the predictions done during CV, or is it predicting each observation after seeing all of the data? If the latter, isn't that going to be an overfit model?